# Link of related question links to different question?

Tags: discussion

I was on [this question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/26238/how-to-stop-viewing-your-story-as-a-film?rq=1) at Writing Stack Exchange. On the side, there is a list of the related questions. I clicked on this question("I have this story all planned out..."):
[image]

For some reason the link actually takes me to [this](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/2100/help-ive-got-writers-block). What is wrong here? Has the question been deleted and the link is to it's duplicate?

Comment: Were you logged in at the time?  I know that what Michael says in his answer about redirecting unanswered duplicates applies when you're not logged in; the assumption is that people are coming from Google and just want an answer, so we don't make them click through the extra time.  I was under the impression that it doesn't happen if you're logged in, but maybe I'm wrong on that.  (It doesn't happen to me, but there are several areas where what mods see is different, so that doesn't tell me anything.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio I just tested this and after logging out I get the behaviour outlined in this question, while I am first directed to the duplicate when logged in.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I was logged in.

Comment: @Xcoder oh wow.  I didn't think it was supposed to work like that.  Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the related questions sidebar for [How to stop viewing your story as a film](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/26238/2533), I do see a link to [I have this story all planned out, why can't I write it?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/23890/2533)

That question, in turn,

- has not been deleted
- has a few upvotes
- has a few comments
- has no answers of its own
- is closed as a duplicate of [Help! I've got Writer's Block](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/2100/2533)

especially the last two of which is probably the reason why the system immediately redirects you to the latter (earlier) question, which does have answers *and* is still open (though protected).

If you turn on the network monitor developer tool in your web browser (in Firefox, with the Firebug add-on installed, by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> and selecting the "Net" tab, then setting it to "Persist" and "HTML"; I suspect other browsers are similar but different), you'll see that there's an initial request for the expected `https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/23890/i-have-this-story-all-planned-out-why-cant-i-write-it?rq=1` to which the server responds with a "302 Found" redirection, which is followed by a request for `https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/2100/help-ive-got-writers-block` which is the question you end up seeing.

It looks to me like the sidebar isn't taking into account the found question's duplicate-ness, and when you browse to the question (by any means; I get the same behavior without going through the related questions sidebar, with or without the `?rq=1` at the end of the URL) you're redirected to what the system thinks you're going to find more useful than an almost two years old, unanswered, duplicate question.

If this wasn't about such a widely linked-to question, you'd likely readily see the question you saw in the "related" sidebar under the "linked" sidebar heading instead. For me, it shows up as #2 on the list, but that could be just a coincidence this once. You can certainly see it if you click through the [see more linked questions](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/2100?lq=1) under the "linked" heading.